# Any thing about How to Design Components mentioned in How to Design Programs?

Tags: software-design

I've just started reading How to Design Programs (2nd edition) on [htdp.org](https://htdp.org)

There are several notes in this book mentioned next volume called How to Design Components (e.g. the 3rd note in [part one](https://htdp.org/2019-02-24/part_one.html)), however, I just can't google anything about the 2nd volume book.

I'm wondering why it is so hard to find any information about the latter volume. Has it finished? If it has not finished yet, how can I get information about the book?

Comment: This question is off-topic here. We're not a status site for books, projects, or future plans of software or tools. Contact the author(s) directly for status updates. This site is for programming (code) or programmers tools related questions. More info is available in the [help].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first author provides more information [on his website](https://felleisen.org/matthias/htdc.html):

> We have decided to provide the draft of ["How to Design Classes" (pdf)](https://felleisen.org/matthias/HtDC/htdc.pdf)
>   on an "as is" basis for now. You are free to download and print it.